# How to run datatable against stored procedure to update database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I used OleDB to import the Excel File.  (No problems there.)

I need to connect to the database and call a stored procedure that is essentially going to update my DB.

In the database, I need to match the primary key with one of the columns so that the right records are updated respectfully.

If you need more information I can provide.

Brand new to coding sorry if this is an easy question or too general.

Code so far:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                    foreach (string doc in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp", "*.XLS"))
                    {
                        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", doc);
                        string workSheet = "Sheet1";
                        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + workSheet + "$]", connectionString);
                        var importedExcelTable = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(importedExcelTable);

                        DataTable newExcelTable = new DataTable();
                        foreach (MileFile row in importedExcelTable.Rows)
                        {
                            DataRow mileFileRow = importedExcelTable.NewRow();
                            mileFileRow["TaxingDistrictID"] = row.TaxingDistrictID;
                            mileFileRow["YearMonth"] = row.YearMonth;
                            mileFileRow["Mileage"] = row.Mileage;
                            mileFileRow["MileageAmount"] = row.MileageAmount;
                            mileFileRow["FipsCode"] = row.FipsCode;

                            newExcelTable.Rows.Add(mileFileRow);

                            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=;database=test;uid=sa;pwd=");
                            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("[job]_[SPROC GOES HERE)", connection);
                            selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            SqlParameter dbParam = selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MileFileRow",newExcelTable);
                            dbParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Strucutred;
                        }
```

Comment: Too general.  Specifics such as table names and column names would help.

Comment: I just edited my comment and added some code. I know that after the newExcelTable the connection is not correct.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg - The Column Names in the Excel File are (County Name, Township Name, Mileage, MileageAmount, FipsCode) and the Column names in the Database (TaxingDistrictID(PK), CountyName, TownshipName, Mileage, MileageAmount, FipsCode and a few more).  I need to match the TaxingDistrictID to the FipsCode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of a c# method that is updating a table based on a stored procedure

```
   using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStringGoesHere))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("STOREDPROCEDURENAME_Goes_Here", sqlcon))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                {

                    sqlcon.Open(); //Open the Connection and then begin a SQL Transaction 

                    using (SqlTransaction sqltran = sqlcon.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        comm.Transaction = sqltran;   //begin tran      
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        comm.Parameters.Add("@OBJECTID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = csvOfIds;
                        comm.Parameters.Add("@ANOTHERPARAMETER", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value= "TEST";
                        int result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Execute Query
                        sqltran.Commit();//Commit SQL transaction
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Rows have been affected", result), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); //Show how many rows were affected
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No I think I am ok with the Stored Procedure.  I am having problem simply with the syntax of how to connect to database and how to use the Stored Procedure to update the database.

Comment: I used OleDb and saved my import to a new DataTable.  I need to take that table and update my table in the database.

Comment: Should I do that before or after importing my Excel Table.  See my code above in my initial question if that helps.

Comment: After if your using your importing your excel table into your SQL Database

Comment: Ok. Thank you so far. Where I think I am getting stuck is in the SqlCommands when adding data to the database. Do I just call the whole DataTable or do I need to call each DataRow? Right here for example: comm.Parameters.Add("@OBJECTID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = csvOfIds;
                                            comm.Parameters.Add("@ANOTHERPARAMETER", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value= "TEST";

Comment: What is my @OBJECTID?  The DataTable or the actual DataRow? And what is @ANOTHERPARAMETER? A VARIABLE?

Comment: Its a parameter for the Stored Procedure (It may not have any Parameters so this line may be redundant)